# Read URL using jQuery and add class in li so I can hide other li using CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have URL which got page name and using that page name I want to add class on li  so I can hide other li using CSS. All ul li list on other page and want to do when page load. For example URL: www.abc.com/jsp/templates/page_elements/uk/common/content.jsp?&page=OrderPayment-5

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-4">4</a></li>
        <li class="hide"><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-5">5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I am new in jQuery and confused how to do that.

Comment: Where is the URL coming from? `window.location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var link = window.location;
var pram = getURLParameter(link, 'page');
if(pram === 'OrderPayment-1')
{
 // add your class to hide first li 
 $('#listQue li').eq(0).css('display', 'none');
 or
 $('#listQue li').eq(0).addClass("hide");
}
if(pram === 'OrderPayment-2')
{
 // add your class to hide second li 
 $('#listQue li').eq(1).css('display', 'none');
 or
 $('#listQue li').eq(1).addClass("hide");
}
});
function getURLParameter(url, name) {
    return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url) || [, null])[1];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. I am still confused. Please guide me. <ul id="listQue">
   <li><a href='/jsp/customerservice/us/common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-1'>Which cards do you accept?</a></li>
   <li><a href='/jsp/customerservice/us/common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-2'>Can I change my order?</a></li>
   <li><a href='/jsp/customerservice/us/common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-3'>I donâ€™t want to receive the next quarterly selection. What should I do?</a></li>
  </ul>

Comment: what you are confused about ? i can't understand

Comment: how to compare param to link and hide that li. I cannot use if conditions because i need to compare and hide dynamically.

Comment: did you need to compare and hide in page load or what ?

Comment: if(pram === 'OrderPayment-1') here I think need some function which read url from page for ex : <a href="/jsp/customerservice/us/common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPay‌​ment-1">blaa blaa blaa</a> and compare with pram and then add class hide to li. It has to be on page load

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear much. I am new in this jquery and stackoverflow

Comment: compare anything like what ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li a").click(function (event) {
           $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
        });
    });
```

If you need to get the class name changed, you should give the anchor tag attribute `target=_blank`

```
<li><a href="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-1" target="_blank">1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all and make the link that is currently active have a class active. And make sure that one has a display set.

I think this ought to do the trick

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var pathnamePart = pathname.split('/uk/');

$('ul').find('li').each(function(){
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');    
    if($this.find('a').attr('href') == pathnamePart[1]){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (albeit currently untested):

```
$('ul li a').addClass(function(){
    return this.href == window.location ? 'active' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get url using options below

```
var pathname = $(location).attr('href'); //jquery
var pathname = window.location.pathname; //javascript
```

next split the string to get what u need using jquery substring()

```
if(pathname.indexOf("common") >= 0){
   var url = pathname.substring(pathname.indexOf("common"))
}
```

now compare it with the value in li using string compare. If you get a match you should know how to hide other li's.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var test=$("li").each(function(){
 var url=$(this).find('a').attr('href');
 if(url=="common/customer_service_question.jsp?page=OrderPayment-3")
 {
     //set hide css to the div.
     $(this).hide();
 }
```